# Android Push Notification Heartbeat Network Package

Tags: android, notifications, push, google-cloud-messaging, heartbeat

I'm new on sending push notifications on android. I try to send push notification for my testing application periodically. But sometimes device can't receive the notification. I searched about it and i think the problem is because of connection lost between server and my device. I think the solution is sending an heartbeat network packet on the push connection but i don't know how can i do it and to which server i should do it?

There is an application on google play store called as Push Notifications Fixer and i think this work is what i want to do

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560448/how-to-avoid-delay-in-android-gcm-messages-change-heartbeat. However, it's not the final solution, see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/fslYqYrULto/lU2D3Qe1mugJ