# FCM android client randomly stops receiving data messages

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented FCM on my server with an Android client, and it worked fine for a while. All of a sudden, the client stopped receiving notifications for 5-10 minutes at a time, after which it would get all the pending notifications at once. The logs show that the server is sending the messages correctly.
When the message queue gets stuck, not even test messages from the Firebase console get through.

The only relevant thing I've found in the official documentation was regarding [the lifetime of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime):

> If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules). When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to the device.

But my network is working fine, and this issue has arisen on other networks and clients as well. When I freshly install the app, a new token is being generated and successfully received by my server. It's just the server-to-client messages that aren't going through.

**How can I determine if the connection is established and fix it? Or what else could be the cause of this?**

This is my client-side code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
        <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <service
            android:name=".service.NotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**NotificationService.java**

```java
public class NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationService";
    private static String token;

    public NotificationService() {
        token = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(App.getContext())
                .getString("firebase-token", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }
                        token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: token = " + token);
                        PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(App.getContext())
                                .edit()
                                .putString("firebase-token", token)
                                .apply();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, "Received message of size " + remoteMessage.getData().size());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int left = -1, right = -1;
                    if (remoteMessage.getData().get("left") != null) {
                        left = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getData()
                                .get("left")));
                    }
                    if (remoteMessage.getData().get("right") != null) {
                        right = Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getData()
                                .get("right")));
                    }


                    if (remoteMessage.getData().get("REFRESH") != null) {
                        Util.sendTitleBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                left, right,
                                Util.REFRESH_TITLE);
                    } else {
                        Util.sendTitleBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                left, right,
                                Util.TITLE_DATA_RECEIVED);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static String getToken() {
        if (token == null) {
            token = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(App.getContext())
                    .getString("firebase-token", null);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Code for server-side
**FirebaseMessagingService.java**

```java
public class FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(FirebaseMessagingService.class);
    private static FirebaseMessagingService instance;

    /**
     * Path to resource file that contains the credentials for Admin SDK.
     */
    private final String keyPath = "firebase-adminsdk.json";

    /**
     * Maps a token list to each topic Object.
     */
    private static Map<Object, List<String>> topicTokenMap;

    public synchronized static FirebaseMessagingService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FirebaseMessagingService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private FirebaseMessagingService() {
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the Firebase service account using the credentials from the
     * json file found at keyPath.
     */
    private void init() {
        try {
            InputStream serviceAccount
                    = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyPath);
            if (serviceAccount != null) {
                FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials
                                .fromStream(serviceAccount))
                        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
                        .build();

                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
                logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: init successful");
            } else {
                logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: Input stream null from"
                        + " path: " + keyPath);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: Failed to get credentials "
                    + "from inputStream." + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends the messages given as parameters to the list of tokens mapped to
     * the given topic Object.
     *
     * @param topic
     * @param messages
     */
    public void sendMessage(Object topic,
            Map<String, String> messages) {
        logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: sending Message "
                + messages.toString());
        try {
            if (topicTokenMap != null) {
                List<String> tokenList = topicTokenMap.get(topic);
                if (tokenList != null) {
                    tokenList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
                    MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
                            .putAllData(messages)
                            .addAllTokens(tokenList)
                            .build();
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(message);
                    logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: message sent successfully");
                }
            }
        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException ex) {
            logger.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the token given as a parameter to the topic Object.
     *
     * @param topic
     * @param token
     */
    public void registerTokenToTopic(Object topic, String token) {
        if (topicTokenMap == null) {
            topicTokenMap = new HashMap<Object, List<String>>();
        }
        List<String> tokens = topicTokenMap.get(topic);
        if (tokens == null) {
            tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        if (!tokens.contains(token)) {
            tokens.add(token);
        }
        topicTokenMap.put(topic, tokens);
    }

    /**
     * Unregisters all instances of the token given as a parameter from the topic
     * given.
     *
     * @param topic
     * @param token
     */
    public void unregisterTokenFromTopic(Object topic, String token) {
        if (topicTokenMap != null) {
            List<String> tokens = topicTokenMap.get(topic);
            if (tokens != null) {
                tokens.removeAll(Collections.singleton(token));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Looks for a topic that has a field with the name equal to topicFieldName
     * and the value equal to topicFieldValue and sends a notification to the
     * tokens subscribed to that topic, telling them to ask for an update.
     *
     * @param topicFieldName
     * @param topicFieldValue
     */
    public void notifyChangeForTopicField(String topicFieldName,
            Object topicFieldValue) {
        logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: notifyChangeForTopicField: "
                + "topicFieldValue = " + topicFieldValue.toString());

        Map<String, String> messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        messageMap.put("REFRESH", "true");

        if (topicTokenMap != null
                && topicTokenMap.entrySet() != null
                && topicTokenMap.entrySet().size() > 0) {
            Iterator it = topicTokenMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    Object topic = pair.getKey();
                    logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: "
                            + "notifyChangeForTopicField topic = " + topic.toString());
                    Field field = topic.getClass().getDeclaredField(topicFieldName);
                    logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: "
                            + "notifyChangeForTopicField field = " + field.toString());
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    logger.debug("FirebaseMessagingService: "
                            + "notifyChangeForTopicField field contains topic: "
                            + (field.get(topic) != null ? "true" : "false"));
                    if (field.get(topic) != null
                            && field.get(topic).equals(topicFieldValue)) {
                        sendMessage(topic, messageMap);
                        break;
                    }
                    it.remove();
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FirebaseMessagingService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FirebaseMessagingService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FirebaseMessagingService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FirebaseMessagingService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: after a few more tests I've found that when one client stops working, the others receive the messages just fine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902751/10702209
What happened was that I was getting router timeouts after 5 minutes, randomly. I've fixed the issue by manually sending out heartbeats to FCM after 4 minutes, instead of the default 15 minutes.

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT"));
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));
```

I've implemented this fix a couple of months ago and haven't had the issue come up again since.

Answer (score 1):

Your `onMessageReceived()` looks a bit overkill to me. I do not think you have to create your own Handler to process data. Just stick to the Firebase example: [FirebaseExample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/256c7e1e6e1dd2be7025bb3f858bf906fd158fa0/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/kotlin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt#L26-L61)

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")
        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
          // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
          scheduleJob()
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks. Tbh I don't remember what the logic behind making a handler was at the time, however, my problem is that the message never reaches the client, and onMessageReceived is never called.

Comment: okay, maybe you can increase the priority: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)

Comment: I've read about that, but I use FCM for a counter. Users scan items, the server processes the items, and sends back the updated counter for how many items have been processed. The user doesn't need to get notified of its change if the app is in the background, and the users won't interact with the notification outside of viewing it while using the app."High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized." I'm thinking the messages would get de-prioritized quickly

Comment: Also, "By default, notification messages are sent with high priority, and data messages are sent with normal priority." when I'm sending test messages from the firebase console, I am sending notifications, so implicitly high priority, and they don't get through. I've added an edit to my initial q, I've tested it with 3 devices and one got stuck for 10 mins while the other 2 worked fine.

Comment: As far as I understand your intention I think you misuse FCM. I would use Firestore(FS) and CloudFunctions(CF). You can [trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#kotlin+ktx) a CF from you client. The CF(on serverside) can process data and set a counter which is stored in the FS. Your client is listening to the FS and can update in [realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Comment: I will have to read more in depth about it, thanks